# Create Hybrid Connection Azure Rest API

Tags: c#, azure, biztalk-services

I am trying to create a hybrid connection in Azure BizTalk service using rest API. Nevertheless, I am receiving this error:

```
<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Code>InternalError</Code>
  <Message>The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.</Message>
</Error>
```

Request:

```
PUT https://management.core.windows.net/36be0e4b-0a10-4b12-8b1c-6aefd3df3fe9/cloudservices/Default-BizTalk-South-Central-US/resources/biztalkservices/~/biztalk/qwbiztalkservice/hybridconnection/namenewhybridconnection HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/xml
x-ms-version: 2012-08-01
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: management.core.windows.net
Content-Length: 152
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<HybridConnectionInput xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\">
  <HostName>myhost</HostName>
  <Port>443</Port>
</HybridConnectionInput>
```

Documentation reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn743828.aspx